# How to pass different set of data to train and test without splitting a dataframe. (python)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science, training-data

I have gone through multiple questions that help divide your dataframe into train and test, with scikit, without etc.

But my question is I have 2 different csvs ( 2 different dataframes from different years). I want to use one as train and other as test?

How to do so for LinearRegression / any model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Load the datasets individually.
- Make sure they are in the same format of rows and columns (features).
- Use the `train` set to `fit` the model.
- Use the `test` set to `predict` the output after training.

```py
# Load the data
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Split features and value
# when trying to predict column "target" 
X_train, y_train = train.drop("target"), train["target"]
X_test, y_test = test.drop("target"), test["target"]

# Fit (i.e. train) model
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict
pred = reg.predict(X_test)

# Score
accuracy = reg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Yes, `X_train` and `X_test` must have the same sequence of columns (features).

Comment: Hi, I think you forget to add X_ and y_ prefixes to "load the data" one? :)

Answer (score 0):

please skillsmuggler what about the X_train and X_Test how I can define it because when I try to do that it said NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, it is a bit incorrect. Please add this after the first three lines

y_train = train[:, :1]  #if y is only one column
X_train = train[:, 1:]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't edit the first answer which is almost there. There is some code missing though...

```
# Load the data
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

y_train = train[:, :1]  #if y is only one column
X_train = train[:, 1:]

# Fit (train) model
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict
pred = reg.predict(X_test)

# Score
accuracy = reg.socre(X_test, y_test)
```